# Why does SSJ4 look so cruel?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-gt

I've not watched GT, I'm a big DB fan but I've honestly not watched a whole lot of the actual material just due to not being able to get my hands on it. Every time I see SSJ4, whether it's Goku or Vegeta or whatever, they just look cruel. It makes sense with Vegeta, he's a cruel person. But Goku is really only cruel when you push him way past his limits and cross lines that aren't okay to cross. Is there are reason in lore as to why SSJ4 consistently looks so cruel?

Comment: SSJ4 is essentially a saiyan's most primal form of power, so design wise, they went for a very primal, strong and aggresive looking form.